# What is the most effective way to lock down external dependency "versions" in Golang?

Tags: go

By default, Go pulls imported dependencies by grabbing the latest version in master (github) or default (mercurial) if it cannot find the dependency on your GOPATH.  And while this workflow is quite simple to grasp, it has become somewhat difficult to tightly control.  Because all software change incurs some risk, I'd like to reduce the risk of this potential change in a manageable and repeatable way and avoid inadvertently picking up changes of a dependency, especially when running clean builds via CI server or preparing to deploy.

What is the most effective way I can pin (i.e. lock down or capture) a package dependency so I don't find myself unable to reproduce an old package, or even worse, unexpectedly broken when I'm about to release?

---- Update ----

Additional info on the [Current State of Go Packaging](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_IJTRD6dDQvyCfyim4KJexq8ZrKUPvUd3GMSA8cw8A4/edit).  While I ended up (as of 7.20.13) capturing dependencies in a 3rd party folder and managing updates (ala Camlistore), I'm still looking for a better way...

[Here is a great list of options](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/PackageManagementTools).

Also, be sure to see the [go 1.5 vendor/ experiment](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/183cc0cd41f06f83cb7a2490a499e3f9101befff) to learn about how go might deal with the problem in future versions.

Comment: The recommendation I've heard: do the import from external sources manually, and include using relative paths instead of automatic ones.

Comment: Relative path are certainly not recommended, as there is talk to remove their support from the Go tools altogether.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might find the way [Camlistore](http://camlistore.org/) does it interesting.

See the [third party directory](https://github.com/bradfitz/camlistore/tree/master/third_party) and in particular the `update.pl` and `rewrite-imports.sh` script.  These scripts update the external repositories, change imports if necessary and make sure that a static version of external repositories is checked in with the rest of the camlistore code.

This means that camlistore has a completely repeatable build as it is self contained, but the third party components can be updated under the control of the camlistore developers.

Answer (score 7):

There is a project to help you in managing your dependencies. Check [gopack](https://github.com/d2fn/gopack)

Answer (score 5):

**godep**

I started using [godep](https://github.com/tools/godep) early last year (2014) and have been very happy with it (*it met the concerns I mentioned in my original question*).  I am no longer using custom scripts to manage the **vendoring** of dependencies as godep just takes care of it.  It has been excellent for ensuring that no drift is introduced regardless of timing or a machine's package state.  It works with the existing mechanism of `go get` and introduces the ability to pin (`godep save`) and restore (`godep restore`) based on Godeps/godeps.json.

Check it out:

https://github.com/tools/godep

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in tooling for this in go. However you can fork the dependencies yourself either on local disk or in a cloud service and only merge in upstream changes once you've vetted them.

Answer (score 1):

The 3rd party repositories are *completely* under your control. 'go get' clones tip, you're right, but you're free to checkout any revision of the cloned-by-go-get or cloned-by-you repository. As long as you don't do 'go get -u', nothing touches your 3rd party repositories already sitting at your hard disk.

Effectively, your external, locally cloned, dependencies are *always* locked down by default.

Comment: Although to be clear, this default behavior locks down your dependencies for **this specific computer only**. If you install your exact same package on another computer, it may download and install completely different versions of your 3rd party dependencies. Until there is a better way embraced by a majority of the community, the fork your deps or check-in your deps in version control (see the Camlistore answer) seems to be the next best thing for large scale projects.

Comment: Yep, understood. But as @PuerkitoBio alludes to, I cannot guarantee that a machine hasn't inadvertently introduced a different version of a package (depending on when they ran _go get_) **without taking some additional steps** (e.g. forking or checking 3rd party repo packages into source control, etc).  My intent is to find out what additional steps folks are taking to manage this (especially when multiple developer machines are involved or rebuilding CI machines).

Comment: @PuerkitoBio sure, but assuming, all dependend libs are hosted on github, you could preserve states by cloning used repos. Isn't that the way to eliminate over 95% of all worries?